# Accidentally changed system clock while browsing - Tor stopped connecting, but was my identity revealed?

Tags: anonymity

I accidentally changed the system clock a few months into the future in the middle of a Tor browser session.  The browser stopped responding, but would the failed attempts to connect to pages before I realized what was going on reveal my identity?

Answer (score 1):

No, this does not reveal your identity.
It does as you say - prevent Tor from connecting, since it needs the clock to be set correctly to your timezone.

Comment: which timezone doesn't actually matter, it just needs to be somewhat accurate (as in, convertible to reasonably correct utc - not sure about how much leeway there is ...)